# Does anyone know C++ XML parser/writer similar to .Net's XML Document?

Tags: c++, xml, nsxmlparser

I'm writing a native C++ project and I need a simple XML parser/writer. I already know XmlDocument in C#, so something similar could be quite good, but if there isn't, does anyone know a quick-to-use XML parser/writer?

I'm trying to shorten my "learning of the library" time to minimum.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using RapidXML (http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/).
For me, its intuitive, and was really easy to learn.

No body recommended it so I added my own answer :-\ ...

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few you can consider:

1. Xerces
2. TinyXML
3. libxml++
4. Expat Xml
5. XmlLite

Answer (score 1):

I've used TinyXML, and it's worked reasonably well for what I've needed. My needs weren't terribly demanding though. At least when I used it, it didn't deal with DTD/XSD at all, so if you need to handle those it's probably not an option.